# Server Sent Events In a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a requirement to implement Server Sent Events capability in a micro service. The application in question runs in a Kubernetes cluster of two pods. However, I don't believe Server Sent Events in a clustered environment will reliably notify all clients of events they have registered for, for the following reason. As an example, client 1 is registered for notifications with the application instance running in pod 1. Client 2 is registered for notifications with the application instance running in pod 2. The next time the event in question occurs, it is handled successfully by the application running in pod 1 (since for whatever reason that is where the load balancer directed it to). So client 1 will be notified of the event, but client 2 will not, since the application running in pod 2 has no idea of what just took place on pod 1. And so forth for subsequent events (next request might go to pod 2, for example).

So I'm thinking of moving towards using reactive streams instead.

Does anyone disagree with my take on implementing SSE's where the application will run in a clustered environment?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: What about this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694121/handling-server-sent-events-across-multiple-pods

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental problem is with holding state information in the pod(s) itself.

A server running in a Kubernetes environment needs to be completely stateless. Not just so that it doesn't matter which pod the load-balancer sends the request to. But more fundamentally, Kubernetes expects to be able to shut down a pod and start a new one without it having any effect on the application. If state is held in the server then that state will be lost when the pod is shut down.

Given this, a good way to implement event-driven processes is to use a message broker. Whenever an event occurs a message is sent, via the broker, to all instances of the server. In your particular case this would trigger the relevant server instance(s) to send that event out via server sent events.

There's one nasty gotcha with using server sent events in a Kubernetes environment, although this would also apply to any push-based mechanism where the client holds a connection open to the server (which essentially is all of them). When Kubernetes shuts down a pod, all clients connected to that pod will be disconnected. So the client needs to be prepared for this and to reconnect automatically continue seamlessly where it left off.