# Handling server sent events across multiple pods

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, redis, server-sent-events

I am working on a NodeJS based server that exposes `/events` endpoint, to send events to client via sse. Alongside this endpoint I have multiple routes for POST request handling.

I am trying to figure out how to set all of this up in a way that works for multiple pods. Right now I have load balancer setup to keep connection between user and pod alive until client disconnects, however when client makes post requests these can be routed to different pods.

I need to ensure that each pod can emit a message with user id and that this event is caught by correct pod that has open connection with the user and sent to the client.

I have considered redis for this, but am wondering if NodeJS or Kubernetes exposes something that doesn't require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it with Services or through the loadbalancer.

With service you can use session affinity :

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
```

with the loadbalancer sticky sessions :

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/